# How do I hide the Print preview dialogue on Chrome ver59 (using Win 7)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, printing, receipt

I know that this topic has been talked about before but I can't seem to get it working. I'm currently printing to an Epson TM88V Receipt Printer via Chrome - I have this set as my default printer. I am in Kiosk mode. The problem is that I briefly see the print preview appear - I don't want to see this. If I use --disable-print-preview I then get presented with the Windows Printer dialogue which I have to confirm. All I want to do is print a Receipt without seeing any dialogues appear